# Loading GoogleMaps with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I'm trying to consistently load Google Maps on this page;
http://staging.meetlincoln.co.uk/cathedral-centre

I have recently switched over to use RequireJS and have gotton over some of the complications with jQuery but seem to be having issues loading Google Maps. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't.

I was wondering if someone might be able to help?

At present the page has the following code;

```
<script data-main="/static/js/site" src="/static/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

The site.js has the following code;

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/static/js'
});
```

I'm also loading in a [maps.js](https://gist.github.com/neilbradley/c95e3ddd4478c1f64390) script on this page that has all of the necessary Google Maps code for the map and directions functions that appear right down the bottom of the page.

I have read numerous articles about how to get Google Maps working with RequireJS but just can't seem to crack it. I'm not sure if it's because my maps.js requires both jQuery and google maps to run.

Apologies for the rather verbose question and I appreciate it might not be enough to help with a response. :(

Comment: are you setting a width and height?

Comment: Hi @FutoRicky, yes I have `div.map{width: 100%;height: 500px;}`

Comment: Try the width as pixels and not percentage

Comment: let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks FutoRicky. I'll give that a try but I'm not sure that's the issue. The map in my case needs to be 100% width and we have them working on other sites like that, just without requirejs.

Comment: I worked with google maps before and I had a similar problem where I could not use percentages in the width nor height

Comment: So I changed the width to a px value and it works more times than it doesn't now, but it still fails every 1 or 2 page loads. :(

Comment: How are you loading google maps sdk. You need to use [async plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins#plugins) for that.